# Subscript out of range (Error 9) for importing data

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy two seperate colums of data from one workbook to another.

Here is my code:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=file & "\GSP - " & months(numMonth) & " 1-" & numdays (numMonth) & " " & tYear & " - Prem.xls", _
Origin:=xlWindows, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tDay).Activate
range("AA6:AA40").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows(fileM & ".xls").Activate
Sheets("Summary").Activate
range("C3:C37").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close
ActiveWindow.Close

Workbooks.Open Filename:=file & "\GSP - " & months(numMonth) & " 1-" & numdays(numMonth) & " " & tYear & " - Prem.xls", _
Origin:=xlWindows, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(tDay).Activate
range("AA84:AA118").Select
Selection.Copy

Windows(fileM & ".xls").Activate
Sheets("Summary").Activate
range("H3:H37").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close
ActiveWindow.Close
```

When the macro finishes running, the second copy is not completed and I am left with Error 9 at the break on the second Windows(fileM & ".xls").Activate'

Comment: What's the value of `tDay` right before it fails?  Odds are it's one more than the number of sheets in your workbook (if it's an integer).

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of problems with this code.  As has been mentioned, you are not defining tDay.  I assume this is being defined elsewhere, else you wouldn't be getting as far as you are.

Using `ActiveWorkbook` should be avoided whenever possible, since it may not always be the workbook that you expect.  Much better to create a `Workbook` variable and assign it to the selected workbook; then use it instead.  I suspect this is the cause of your problem -- ActiveWorkbook.Close isn't closing the one you expect.

Next, you are opening the file, copying from it, closing it, and repeating.  Why not leave it open?

Next, you don't always need to call .Select in order to take action on a range.  You can call .Copy and .PasteSpecial directly from the `Range` object.

I'm making some assumptions about your intent, but the following code incorporates the suggestions above.

```
Sub foo()
    Dim wkbGSP As Workbook
    Dim wkbFileM As Workbook

    tday = "sheet1"

    Set wkbFileM = Workbooks(fileM & ".xls")

    Workbooks.Open Filename:=file & "\GSP - " & months(numMonth) & " 1-" & numdays (numMonth) & " " & tYear & " - Prem.xls", _
    Origin:=xlWindows, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True

    Set wkbGSP = ActiveWorkbook

    wkbGSP.Sheets(tday).Range("AA6:AA40").Copy

    wkbFileM.Sheets("Summary").Activate
    Range("C3:C37").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    wkbGSP.Sheets(tday).Activate
    Range("AA84:AA118").Copy

    wkbFileM.Sheets("Summary").Activate
    Range("H3:H37").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    wkbGSP.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your tDay value is not found such as out of range or no such sheet number.  How do you define this value?